# Check if variable exists in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I've got a PersistenceSet and would like to check if it contains a certain variable.

**How can I check in the JSTL whether subitem exists or not?**

However when I try to access a non-existant variable like this:

```
<c:if test="${not empty item.subitem}">       
   <c:out value="${item.subitem}" /><br />
</c:if>
```

I get a PropertyNotFoundException:

> Property 'subitem' not found on type com.company.classname

Comment: Are you sure that you have defined the setter and the getter method for this property?

Comment: Yeah, its handled by Spring Roo. It works but I also want to check PersistenceSets which don't contain the subitem-property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is clear that standard setter/getter is not available for `subitem` in the class

If you want to check if the property is available for the class you can go for following tweak

using [`c:catch`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/catch.html)

```
<c:catch var="exception">${item.subitem}</c:catch>
<c:if test="${exception==null}">subitemnot available.</c:if>
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I check inside the JSTL whether subitem is available or not? I don't want to define a table tag for all of my classes.

Comment: Your check (not empty) didn't work. I edited to check against null, which works perfectly.